# LINQ: Convert to IEnumerable from WhereSelectEnumerableIterator

Tags: linq, ienumerable

How do you convert a **`WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<foo, EntitySet<blah>>`** to a **`IEnumerable<blah>`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: I've used SelectMany

from MSDN:

> Projects each element of a sequence to
>   an IEnumerable and flattens the
>   resulting sequences into one sequence.